# Overleaf Ctrl+/ doesn't work

Tags: overleaf, shortcut

I'm trying to comment multiple lines throughout my text using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (I'm using Overleaf). It doesn't work! Anyone knows why? Is there another command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I already found out that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> works! :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, Ctrl + shift + 7 worked (French keyboard, supposedly)